# How do I stop popup windows in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup, pyinstaller

I have a GUI python program that I'm building with `Pyinstaller`. It calls several other executables using the `subprocess` module. Every time one of these binaries is called, a popup window associated with the executable opens for the duration of its execution.

How do I stop these from popping up?

Here's what my calls look like:

```
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL).decode()

CMD_BASE  = BLHOST_PATH + " -t 5242000 " + " -u " + " 0x15A2,0x0073 " +  " -j "
CMD_RESET = " -- reset"

run_command(CMD_BASE + CMD_RESET))
```

Here's my pyinstaller .spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
            #TODO:  Change the paths here to match your environment
             pathex=['c:mypath'],
             binaries=[('blhost.exe','tools'),('sdphost.exe','tools'),('ivt_flashloader.bin','tools')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Proj',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='asdf.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='test')
```

Comment: can you at least provide the piece of code with subprocess usage ?

Comment: Gladly I can do that

Comment: I tried your piece of code with 2 different executables and no console is appearing so I would conclude that this is coming from the executables your are calling. Are they your own or can you point to them on the web ?

Comment: Yeah, it's part of the NXP-MCUBootUtility package, called blhost.exe. It's a bit of a convoluted way to download it, but its in this project under NXP-MCUBootUtility/tools/blhost/win/

Comment: https://github.com/JayHeng/NXP-MCUBootUtility is the link

Answer (score 0):

Got it: the NXP-MCUBootUtility exe is generated from Python using pyinstaller and the .spec file shows Console=True, so you will always get a console, unless you rebuild the exe yourself with console=False

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry I should have clarified, the tool I'm using is a different tool that just happens to call some of the same executables as NXP-MCUBootUtility. I updated my question to include my spec if you're still interested

Comment: @PeterKapteyn Please reconsider my answer: I was discussing the way NXP-MCUBootUtility is built, not your own application

Comment: Sorry for the confusion once again, I'm not calling NXPbootutility, I'm calling blhost.exe (which is also called by NXPBootulity)